# How to fix the soft button overlapping the app in Windows Phone?

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, windows-phone, hybrid-mobile-app

The bottom part of the app is being covered by the soft buttons in Nokia Lumia 640 XL and similar phones.

I am developing an app using Cordova, backbone JS.

[image]

Comment: Why not actually Show your problem

Comment: @IdanAdar have uploaded an image.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to change the size of your tiles to fit into the screen.

Comment: But then the phones which have hardware buttons will have blank space at the bottom. I want to know if there is a way to detect if the phone has soft buttons or hardware button so that I can align the tiles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot shows a device with on-screen buttons.
You have to support both devices with on-screen buttons and off-screen buttons. As far as I know newer devices now always come with on-screen.

That is, you have to make your app UI and design support running on screens with height < 800 points.

Take that into account when designing touch areas like buttons.

You can learn more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/index) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the actual height of the screen might come handy in this case. Most of the initial phone screens were 480x800, for soft buttons it was approximately 480x853. So you would have a difference of around 50 pixels. Get height using:

```
double actualHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```